# Why can equals not be inferred in HashSets where the type is specified?

Tags: java, object, collections, hash, equals

I don't understand something silly in Java and was hoping you could clear it up for me.

I have defined `Hashset<Point> myHashSet = new HashSet<Point>();`

Then, I create two equal Point points, `Point p1 and Point p2`, and put them in different variables/memory locations. Then I override the .equals() method for `public boolean equals(Point other)` and added my first point, p1, to the HashSet.

Then I call `System.out.println(myHashSet.contains(p2)); // prints false`

Why can the compiler not infer "Oh, this hashset is of type Point" from the  when it is being created and say "I should check to see if Point has overridden the default equals method...yup, let's call that one!".

Instead, I believe it calls the generic equals method for objects, thus comparing memory location, I believe ?

Is the reasoning for this simply that the HashSet could contain a subclass of Point which uses a different Equals method ? This is the only reason I can see for the current behaviour, though I am sure I am overlooking something :). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you override hashCode as well?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I know this must be done also, I was more asking the question of why Java can't infer from the HashSet I have created "This HashSet only contains objects of type Point, so I shouldn't use the Object equals method, I should use the Point one" :)

Comment: Ah - as Peter said, I believe you haven't correctly overridden the equals method. You've overloaded it instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collections use `Object.equals(Object)` which you have to override.  If you create another method like `equals(Point)` it won't call it.

> Instead, I believe it calls the generic equals method for objects, thus comparing memory location, I believe ?

Yes, as the only method which `HashSet` can generically call is `equals(Object)`

> Is the reasoning for this simply that the HashSet could contain a subclass of Point which uses a different Equals method ?

The HashSet has no way of know that you want to use this method instead at runtime.

Comment: Annotating the equals method with `@Override` would be a good way to catch this case.

Comment: Yes, you've overloaded the method instead.

Comment: I know this, I mention that in the question. My question is...why can't it infer from my <Point> in the collection definition that it should call the equals method for Points! :) Wouldn't this make more sense? (I know I am overlooking something, I just can't figure it out). :) Thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: a) it doesn't have access to the class at runtime b) if you have an interface, there is no way to define an equals method on an interface. c) this doesn't work for subclasses. d) if it had access to the class and used reflection to call it, it would be much slower. e) it wouldn't be consistent with how overriding works in general.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks very much for the answer. I am still a little confused, however. I think I am getting a little low-level - but since you're specifying the collection to be of type <Point> it can then only contain items of type Point, so I'm assuming that some metadata is set to say Collection.Type="Point" (to put it in a much more higher level way) - so why can it not check this piece of metadata, check if there is an overridden equals method in the definition of Point, if there is then call that, if not then call the generic Object method?

Sorry, it's difficult to explain what I mean! :)

Comment: Ok, just saw your reply and it is extremely helpful. Thank you. I feel like a newborn child asking annoying questions, but...why doesn't it have access to the class at runtime? How come it can't infer from the <> tags in the collection definition ? Also, I don't really understand what you say about interfaces (I understand the concept/uses of interfaces, but not what it relates to here). Thanks a lot for the patience and sorry again.

Comment: Generics are a compile time feature.  The code for all HashSet is exactly the same and every HashSet will call the same method which is equals(Object)  There is no way for HashSet to know at runtime you use `<Point>` I am not saying it couldn't have been designed that, but it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You should override both equals() and hashCode() according to this doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29, since HashSet use both of these methods to check if objects are equal

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in `public boolean equals(Point other)`, because that is NOT the default equals method defined in the `Object` class.

You must override `public boolean equals(Object other)` (notice Object instead of Point) if you wish the HashMap to use your implementation. See the [the documentation for Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and note also that if you override `equals` you SHOULD also override the `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@Override` annotation. You must have misspelled equals method and its signature.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
```